# How to add an image to a button with GTK4?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I know this question exists [How to add an image to a button with GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070832/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button-with-gtk) but `gtk_button_set_image` is deprecated in gtk4.

Comment: just create a `GtkImage` and `add()` it to the `Button`. The point I think is that specialised code to create child widgets by the `Button` itself is not needed when users can just set up the child they want and add it in.

Comment: Ok, I get it . I just needed to  set it like this : `gtk_button_set_child (GTK_BUTTON (button), image);` where button is GtkButton and image is a GtkImage. Thanks . That was fast .

Comment: Better to `gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button), image)` imo, just looks more right.

Comment: `gtk_container_add()` it's deprecated too in gtk4

Comment: ok, so then use [`gtk_button_set_child()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/unstable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-child)

Comment: if you create the button with `gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic ` and later you add an image with `gtk_button_set_child ` the label is not show or is replaced by the image. Here in archlinux gtk4 4.7

Answer (score 3):

`gtk_button_set_child (GTK_BUTTON (button), image);` where button and image are GtkButton and GtkImage , respectivly .

Answer (score 0):

```
Gtk.Box box = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 5);
box.prepend(new Image.from_icon_name("media-playback-start"));
box.append(new Gtk.Label("Play"));
button.child = box;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.